# 401 unauthorized to access site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

i'm begining with SP2016 server, i create web application on 'https://localhost:32844/ ', and i create site collection under this web application 'https://localhost:32844/sites/lasertest', but when i try to access site, i have this page and error
i'm using IE
[image]

```
401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the "Continue to this website (not recommended)"? It looks like the SSL certificates used in your web application is not issued from a trusted authority.

Comment: when a iclick i have the message 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have added the certificate to trust management in Central Administration> Security> Manage Trust:

[image]

I tested it based on the following article and can access the website well, hope it will be helpful to you:

https://sharepointdiv.wordpress.com/2018/05/04/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013-2016/

Comment: OK, i w'll try it